# Reduce the number of rows in a binary table

Tags: approximation, compression, lossless-compression, lossless

I have a table with a 38 bit binary string at every address. I am trying to figure out what would be the best way of reducing the depth of the table? Say for example that I have 1024 addresses and I want to reduce it to about 100 addresses, such that if I apply one of the 1024- 38 bit binary string on this reduced table, I could classify it as "From the ORIGINAL table" or "Not".

Now the first simple step is to merge any matching records into a single record. What are some more ways of optimizing the depth of binary records? (Lossy reduction is also acceptable)